# Converting a map of map to list of map in java

Tags: java, list, maps, java-stream

I have a java map,

```
Map<Date, Map<String, Integer>> dateTeamCountMap;
```

I want to convert the above map which gives values

```
{28-09-2018={India=14,Australia=16}, 31-09-2018={India=13,Australia=11}}
```

into list of objects of format

```
{{Date:28-09-2018, India:14, Australia:26},{Date:31-09-2018, India:13, Australia:11}}
```

Sorry, am new to stackoverflow. Correct my question if am wrong. Thanks.

I am not able to create a generic list, because the number of teams is always unknown to me.

Comment: What type should your output be?  Is that `ArrayList<Map<String,Object>>` or something different?

Comment: List<Object> is the type am expecting.

Comment: But what type should the objects in the list be?

Comment: @HareshKannan you can't transform `{Date:28-09-2018, India:14, Australia:26}` to Object, since Object has no corresponding fields. You should either declare some data class with such fields or return Map<String,String> instead of Object (if fields are not predefined)

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko I understood your point. This is the structure i have with me. I am having a REST api which expects data to be in that end format. I checked now and it can take Map<String,String> as well. Thanks for your advice guys. Was of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
dateTeamCountMap.forEach((date, nestedMap) -> {
    Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
    temp.put("Date",date);
    nestedMap.forEach((team, count) -> {
        temp.put(team,count);
    });
    list.add(temp);
});
```

If you have a class representing `{Date:28-09-2018, India:14, Australia:26}` then you can create `List<YourClass>` too.

Comment: `nestedMap.forEach((team, count) -> { temp.put(team,count); });` is a complicated way to say `temp.putAll(nestedMap);`. You could simplify this even further by using `Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<>(nestedMap);` to construct the map and copy `nestedMap` in one go.